# How to execute matlab function and save the output in a new file in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, matlab, shell, slurm

This is the first time I'm using matlab scripts.

I have a folder "example" with some input files and matlab scripts. It looks like following:

```
example
   ├──input.score
   ├──input.param
   ├──input.expr
   ├──main.m
   ├──input.m
   ├──dist.m
```

I created a shell script `test.sh` to run `main.m` matlab script which has the function. The function name is `shortmain`

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=8
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=4G
#SBATCH --time=05:59:59

ml MATLAB/r2016a

matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nojvm -r "run main.m"
```

My workload manager is `Slurm`, so I submitted the job like following:

```
sbatch test.sh
```

This had run the function present in `main.m`. But I want to execute this function on input files and save the output in a new file. Below is the function I want to execute on input files.

```
shortmain('input.expr', 'input.score', 'input.param', 'Trans')
```

Not sure how to use this in the shell script and save the output in new file. Any help is appreciated. thanq

Comment: You can add custom folder to your matlab path, so matlab will include the function contained in this folder. Now your can run your custom function using `matlab -r 'yourfunction(arg1,arg2,arg3)'`

Comment: And simply save your output through the matlab script not the bash script.

Comment: Could you please show me an example. thanq

Comment: It's explained [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html?searchHighlight=addpath&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) (the first example)

Comment: Do I need to include that custom function inside shell script?

Comment: Have your read the link ? Everything is explained in the doc, for example if you run `matlab -r statement`: "If statement is the name of a MATLAB function or script, do not specify the file extension and do not use quotation marks. *Any required file must be on the MATLAB search path or in the startup folder*."

Comment: Yes I have read the link. In the main.m matlab script, I added addpath('example') savepath example output.m then in the above mentioned shell script I added this, matlab -r 'shortmain(input.expr, input.score, input.param, Trans)' but didn't work

Comment: Aaaah no ! You have to do that in a normal matlab session ! [what is the matlab-search path](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190256/discussion-between-beginner-and-obchardon).

Comment: @obchardon Could you please answer me in chat. thanq

Answer (score 1):

Rename `main.m` as `shortmain.m` and run

```
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nojvm -r "shortmain('input.expr', 'input.score', 'input.param', 'Trans'); exit"
```